# Why Jenkins pipeline throwing java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.mysql.jdbc.Driver?

Tags: java, mysql, jenkins, jdbc

The exception thrown by Jenkins pipeline.

```
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.mysql.jdbc.Driver
```

I've already installed **Database Plugin** and **MySQL Database Plugin**.

But still I'm getting this exception.

The pipeline code :

```
import groovy.sql.Sql

node('master'){
    Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver")
    def sql = Sql.newInstance("jdbc:mysql://10.10.115.38:3306/test", "root","123456", "com.mysql.jdbc.Driver")
    def rows = sql.execute "select count(*) from test;"
    echo rows.dump()
}
```

Exception message:

```
 Running on Jenkins in /var/jenkins_home/workspace/test-jdbc
 [Pipeline] {
 [Pipeline] }
 [Pipeline] // node
 [Pipeline] End of Pipeline
 java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.mysql.jdbc.Driver
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:382)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:419)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:352)
```

I'm using **Jenkins version 2.222.1**

Comment: The MySQL Connector/J JAR file isn't on the classpath, but the `Class.forName()` line hasn't been needed since 2007.

Answer (score 0):

The reason for this `java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.mysql.jdbc.Driver` is that the MySQL Connector/J jar is missing.

Note: If you are using higher version of MySQL Connector/J, then it is recommended to use `com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver` instead of `com.mysql.jdbc.Driver`

I updated your script.

```
import groovy.sql.Sql

node('master'){
    Class.forName("com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver")
    def sql = Sql.newInstance("jdbc:mysql://10.10.115.38:3306/test", "root","123456", "com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver")
    def rows = sql.execute "select count(*) from test;"
    echo rows.dump()
}
```

Download the jar from here : https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/mysql/mysql-connector-java

Comment: @jugggao previous error is still showing after changing.

Comment: B Show java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver.

Comment: Where should I save the MySQL JDBC connector jar?

Comment: @jugggao where do you save jar in jenkins ?

Comment: /data/jenkins/jenkins/plugins/database-mysql/WEB-INF/lib

database-mysql.jar  mysql-connector-java-8.0.13.jar  protobuf-java-3.6.1.jar

Comment: @jugggao Yeah !!

Comment: @jugggao database-mysql.jar what this jar for

Comment: This jar included in the  jenkins MySQL Database Plugin

Comment: @jugggao Now, test by putting the jar

Comment: In pipeline, I don't know where to put jar.

Comment: @jugggao Sorry but I'm not DevOps guy. I can help with java related things only. Research about where to put jars and how to load them jenkins pipeline.

Comment: Your second reason is incorrect, MySQL Connector/J 8.0.x still contains the `com.mysql.jdbc.Driver` class; it will just print out a warning when loaded, but it will still load the `com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver`. That said, it is recommend to switch to the new classname.